Should I remove "someone" in this sentence?

Take, for example, a person suffering from a dangerous disease or someone whose family depends on them financially.

Grammarly suggested removing "someone," but my teacher didn't say anything about it when correcting my essay. Is that an oversight or is Grammarly wrong?
Personally, I think "someone" is not incorrect, though it's true that I can remove it for conciseness.

Take, for example, someone suffering from a dangerous disease or someone [else] whose family depends on them financially. Since they're both just example scenarios, it makes no difference whether the specific phrasing identifies one hypothetical person (with one of two possible attributes) or two hypothetical people (each having different attributes). You might as well take, for example, one man like this, or another man like that.

Despite the name, Grammarly gives not only grammar correction but general writing advice. When it's not a matter of "right or wrong" but just "better," there's room to disagree. I would distrust a lot of AI advice, but even if this came from a human, I personally feel like your version flows better. While it's usually a good idea to eliminate unnecessary words, you have to make sure you don't eliminate so many that it becomes harder to read.

No, I don't think it's necessarily wrong. There are two slightly different ways of understanding the sentence.

Consider a person who is (a) suffering from disease, or (b) their family's sole breadwinner (different circumstances which might apply to one hypothetical person).
Consider (a) a person suffering from disease, or (b) a person whose family depends on them financially (two different hypothetical people).

